# Merge the "compiling", "compile" and "compilation" tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

Shouldn't the [compiling](/questions/tagged/compiling) and [compile](/questions/tagged/compile) tags be merged with the [compilation](/questions/tagged/compilation) tag, or made a synonym?

Comment: Are you referring to [tag:compiling], or [tag:compile]? In the title you are referring to one, but you are referring to the other one, in the question body.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Apparently both. ;) They are both confusing, and I can't tell them apart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good idea -- I merged them all into [compilation](/questions/tagged/compilation) which had a nice wiki, and set up synonyms.