# Tag merge [cross-compile] + [cross-compiling] => [cross-compilation]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

So the story goes:

- there are 49 questions tagged [cross-compile](/questions/tagged/cross-compile)
- There are 665 questions tagged [cross-compiling](/questions/tagged/cross-compiling)
- There are 0 questions tagged [cross-compilation](/questions/tagged/cross-compilation)

I'm suggesting moving them all to cross-compilation due to precedent in the decision on resolving "compiling", "compile", and "compilation": [Merge the "compiling", "compile" and "compilation" tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105842/merge-the-compiling-compile-and-compilation-tags)

Though [compiler](/questions/tagged/compiler) still exists to distinguish questions about innards or characteristics compilers themselves in absence of any input code, as opposed to problems one is having with a compilation step.

(There are no instances of [cross-compiler](/questions/tagged/cross-compiler), and I guess a narrow question about writing a cross-compiler could be tagged [compiler](/questions/tagged/compiler) and [cross-compilation](/questions/tagged/cross-compilation).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty good suggestion. I agree `compilation` word is good enough to cover all the topics of

- cross-compile
- cross-compiling
- cross-compilers
- cross-compilation

But, tag synonyms might be a better choice than retaging all the questions.

If a merger is what you want, then merging the 49 question of `cross-compile` to `cross-compiling` is a good choice.

Comment: I wanted to tag it tag-merge, but retag-request is the tag-synonym for tag-merge.  *(When someone reads over my shoulder at the sentences I type and sees things like that, they perhaps have just cause for wondering if the things I do on the Internet make sense or are just gibberish.  :P)*

Comment: I think you should remove [tag:cross-compilers] on that list.

Comment: @Tshepang, Please provide an explanation as well.

Comment: That should be reserved for when one is asking about cross-compilers, instead of, for example, cross-compiling.